# Change color in a string array

Tags: android, string, colors

i have 1 listview with some text now i want change "Club" in bold or "Cost: 1 GP, Damage: 1D6" in gray is possible???

```
String[] ad = {"Simple Melee Weapons", "Club\nCost: 1 GP, Damage: 1D6"}
```

Comment: This is hard to answer without the layout you created for this, but to answer your question is you can either use `Spannable` or `Html`

Comment: `Change color in a string array` this is not possible, because a string array is not an object with a visible interface. But you can change the color of a substring in a TextView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Spannable span = new SpannableString(ad[1]);        

span.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GRAY), 0, ad[1].length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

span = new SpannableString(ad[0]);
StyleSpan boldSpan = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
span .setSpan(boldSpan, 0, ad[0].length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Try searching a little bit more. Stack has everything, this question has been asked a million times.

Comment: I can use this on text of simple_list_item_1??

Comment: Of course. You can use it on any string you want. But, if you want to use it in a listview with a default adapter I am afraid you cannot. You will have to create your own adapter implementation in order to modify the appearance of the list elements as you want. I would suggest you though, to try and use recyclerview instead of a listview. It's ten times better since it implements the ViewHolder pattern on its own and it's pretty straight-forward how to use it. If this answer was correct, please mark it so :).

Comment: @LuigiDeSimone if this was the answer to your question, which I think it was, please mark it as correct.